# How to calculate complicated geometrical series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a geometrical series (I don't know if its geometrical series or not):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\rho ^{n}(1-\rho)
$$

how can I simplify it ? ( assume that $ 0 \le \rho \le 1$ )

The last answer in my calculatio should be $\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}$. But I really don't know how ?

Comment: It's not Geometric. It is almost a "Differentiated Geometric series", though. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) for many ways to calculate the sum of such a series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\rho ^{n}(1-\rho)=(1-\rho)\rho\frac{d(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\rho^n)}{d \rho}$$

Now using [Infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) Geometric Series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\rho^n=\frac \rho{1-\rho}=-1-\frac1{\rho-1}$$ as $|\rho|<1$

Comment: How did you do that ? I mean how first statement created ?? I don't get it

Comment: @linker, do you know $$\frac{d(x^n)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: $nx ^{n-1}$ ? so ? whats diffrential ? where did it came from ?

Comment: @linker, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\rho ^n(1-\rho)=(1-\rho)\rho\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n\rho ^{n-1}= $$

Comment: You have made a small mistake. The Geometric is : $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\rho^n=\frac{1}{1-\rho}$

Comment: @Julien, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series, here $a=\rho$

Comment: @Julien no he did it right, you are right to when n starts from 0

Comment: @labbhattacharjee you are awesome :)

Comment: Yes, sorry I read too fast..

Comment: @linker, thanks for your feedback. Btw, have you looked into my other solution?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I really don't know that kind of series, I will take a look it later thnaks anyway <3

Answer (score 1):

Using [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms),  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[a+(n-1)d\right]r^{n-1}=\frac a{1-r}+\frac{rd}{(1-r)^2}\text{  for } |r|<1$$

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\rho^n(1-\rho)=(1-\rho)\rho\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \rho^{n-1}\right)$$

Here,  we have $\displaystyle a=d=1,r=\rho$

Comment: @Dwonvoter, please have a look into the edited version. Wish I could know the mistake here