# Evaluate to find the sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

### $∑_{n=1}^\infty$ $n\over2^{n-1}$

or

1 + $2\over2$ + $3\over4$ + $4\over8$ + $5\over16$ + $\ldots$

How to go about evaluating the above, showing that it sums to 4?

Comment: Just like you compute $\int xe^xdx$, integration by parts.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: Another very similar question is [Why does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ converge to 2?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/441481), which was closed as a duplicate of the question in David Mitra's comment. So this one should be closed as such as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these sorts of problems it is helpful to start with geometric series: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$ If we differentiate this series we find $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}  = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$ This series is valid for all $x \in (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{n}{2^{n-1}} = f'(1)$ where $f(x) = 2 \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^n}{2^n} = 2 \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{2}}$ so that $f'(x) = 2 \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$ and $f'(1) = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

prove this by induction 
$\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{i}{2^{i-1}}=-4\, \left( 1/2 \right) ^{m+1} \left( m+1 \right) -4\, \left( 1/2
 \right) ^{m+1}+4
$

Comment: [Again](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1098214/)?

Comment: yes again or you got the proof it is an exercise for you

Comment: Right. As ridiculous as the other one.