# Limit with subsequences

Tags: limits

I have the following limit

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left({1 \over 2^1}+{3 \over 2^2} + {5 \over 2^3} + \dots + {2n-1 \over 2^n}\right)$$

My idea is to separate it into geometric progressions and rewrite them using the equation for the sum of first terms of a geometric progression. I manage to get one geometric progression but the other elements of the sum don't follow a geometric pattern. Do you have any hints as to how I might separate the terms? Or, alternatively, if there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetico-geometric_series

Comment: Couple of duplicates: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B2n-1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%24&p=1 e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098207/201168